# webview show up with another window in facebook messenger

Tags: facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I've tried to embed my website inside Facebook messenger by that documentation. Unfortunately, my website is popup with new window instead of inside embedded Facebook messenger.

```
"buttons":[
  {
    "type":"web_url",
    "url":"https://petersfancyapparel.com/criteria_selector",
    "title":"Select Criteria",
    "webview_height_ratio": "full",
    "messenger_extensions": true,  
    "fallback_url": "https://petersfancyapparel.com/fallback"
  }
]
```

Please let me know what I've missed to put something in messenger configuration or something else? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to specify your webview_height_ratio if you are using it that way.

From messenger docs :

> Height of the Webview. Valid values: compact, tall, full. N, default
>   is full.

Try `webview_height_ratio = "compact",` instead of  `"webview_height_ratio": "full"`.